V4l2 camera device no longer taking images after small pause
I am trying to use a v4l2 capable camera to take images and evaluate them within my program. The idea is to continously evaluate images taken by the camera within my program, so I'm using C++ and v4l2 to extract those images.
Not being familiar with how v4l2 works, I've looked for simple program samples that show how it can be used to take camera images. I've come across one that pretty much worked, and although I noticed it seemed somewhat cumbersome I quickly had it working with the camera, allowing me to take black and white images and copy them into an external buffer I could provide (while not ideal, it worked well enough and fast enough, even with memcpy'ing the buffer content into my buffer, it would still only take around 8200 microseconds to get an image, which is ideal for a 120fps camera).
However, when trying to work this solution into my software, I noticed that I would no longer receive new images, instead it would always only take the first image it captured and also only take around 1500 microseconds. If I immediately kept reading from the camera, it would remain at 8200 microseconds, always reading new images, but as soon as I'd stop reading from the camera to finish the program setup, it would stop reading new images whenever I called the method "captureImage", and just give me the last surviving it had read.
So I went back to the basic functionality and built the following program, taking the camextractor class from my project.
camextractor.cpp
#include "camextractor.h"

// basecode taken from https://cplusplus.com/forum/unices/280006/ , adapted for this
// HOWEVER, not optimized yet!

template <typename typeXX>
void clear_memory(typeXX* x)
{
    memset(x, 0, sizeof(*x));
}

struct LMSBBB_buffer
{
    void*  start;
    size_t length;
};

struct v4l2_buffer buf;
LMSBBB_buffer* buffers;

CamExtractor::CamExtractor(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

    this->configure();


    // buffers queued, this is setup done!

    //this->captureImage(buf1, 2304000);

    // stop stream (past loop!)

    //this->shutdown();

}

bool CamExtractor::configure()
{
    const char* dev_name = "/dev/video0";
    int width=1920;
    int height=1200;

    this->cam_fd = open(dev_name, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);

    struct v4l2_format format = {0};
    format.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    format.fmt.pix.width = width;
    format.fmt.pix.height = height;
    format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_GREY;//V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV //V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24
    format.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE; //V4L2_FIELD_NONE
    this->xioctl(this->cam_fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &format);

    /*
    if (system("/opt/V4LCam_Extract_Test/bin/test.sh") != 0)
    {
        printf("A command failed!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    */

    printf("Device initialized.\n");

    ///request buffers
    struct v4l2_requestbuffers req = {0};
    req.count = 3; // in order to maintain 120fps, need more buffers than minimum, so cam can keep writing to other buffers while dequeueing one
    std::cout << "Req buffers "<< req.count;
    req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    this->xioctl(this->cam_fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req);

    printf("Buffers requested.\n");


    ///mapping buffers
    buffers = (LMSBBB_buffer*) calloc(req.count, sizeof(*buffers));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < req.count; i++)
    {
        clear_memory(&(buf));

        (buf).type        = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        (buf).memory      = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        (buf).index       = i;

        this->xioctl(this->cam_fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &buf);

        buffers[i].length = (buf).length;
        printf("A buff has a len of: %lu\n",buffers[i].length);
        buffers[i].start = mmap(NULL, (buf).length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, this->cam_fd, (buf).m.offset);

        if (MAP_FAILED == buffers[i].start) {
            perror("Can not map the buffers.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    count_req_buffers = req.count;
    printf("Buffers mapped.\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count_req_buffers; i++)
    {
        clear_memory(&(buf));
        (buf).type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        (buf).memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        (buf).index = i;
        ioctl(this->cam_fd,VIDIOC_QBUF, &(buf));
    }
}

void CamExtractor::xioctl(int cd, int request, void *arg)
{
    int response;
    do
    {
        //ensures we get the correct response.
        response = ioctl(cd, request, arg);
    }
    while (response == -1 && ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN)));

    if (response == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void CamExtractor::captureImage(unsigned char* imageBufferLoc, int bufferLength)
{


    enum v4l2_buf_type type;
    type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    this->xioctl(this->cam_fd,VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type);

    clear_memory(&(buf)); // req_buffer content must be all 0, so wipe buffer
    (buf).type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    (buf).memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    this->xioctl(this->cam_fd,VIDIOC_DQBUF, &(buf));


    // write to provided buffer
    //########################
    memcpy(imageBufferLoc, buffers[(buf).index].start, (buf).bytesused);
    //########################

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count_req_buffers; i++)
    {
        clear_memory(&(buf));
        (buf).type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        (buf).memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        (buf).index = i;
        ioctl(this->cam_fd,VIDIOC_QBUF, &(buf));
    }

}

void CamExtractor::shutdown()
{

    unsigned int toype = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    if(ioctl(this->cam_fd, VIDIOC_STREAMOFF, &toype) == -1){
        perror("VIDIOC_STREAMON");
        exit(1);
    }
}


camextractor.h
#ifndef CAMEXTRACTOR_H
#define CAMEXTRACTOR_H

#include <QObject>
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
//#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
//#include <libv4l2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


class CamExtractor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int cam_fd; // filedescriptor used to represent the camera
    int count_req_buffers;

    public:
        explicit CamExtractor(QObject *parent = nullptr);


    public slots:
        void captureImage(unsigned char* imageBufferLoc, int bufferLength);
        void shutdown();

    signals:
        void imageExtracted(unsigned char* imageBufferLoc, int bufferLength);

    private:
        void xioctl(int cd, int request, void *arg);
        bool configure();
};

#endif // CAMEXTRACTOR_H


main.cpp

#include "camextractor.h"
#include <QFile>

int main(){

    unsigned char* buf1 = new unsigned char[2304000];

    CamExtractor cam{};
    auto p0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cam.captureImage(buf1, 2304000); // first readout, might be slower!
    auto p01 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "\nInitial runtime: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(p01 - p0).count() << " microseconds...\n" << std::flush;



// all these extractions take around 8200 - 8400 microseconds
    for (int i = 1;  i <= 1200; i++)
    {
        auto p1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cam.captureImage(buf1, 2304000);
        auto p2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "\nExtraction runtime: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(p2 - p1).count() << " microseconds...\n" << std::flush;

    }


    std::cout << "sleeping for 10s!" << std::endl;
    sleep(10);

// this extraction somehow only takes 1500 microseconds, when it should take 8000
    auto p10 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cam.captureImage(buf1, 2304000); // first readout, might be slower!
    auto p101 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "\nInitial runtime: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(p101 - p10).count() << " microseconds...\n" << std::flush;


    cam.shutdown();
    auto pEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "\nOverall runtime: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(pEnd - p0).count() << " microseconds...\n" << std::flush;



    return 0;
}



In my actual program, there's no 10 second sleep phase, but instead the program completes other setup routines and starts evaluating the first image received before going back to take another.
I was thinking that I might have to move the whole image extraction to a seperate thread to always keep it running, but it seems like a waste of ressources, as most images would just be skipped anyway (image evaluation is taking 20-50 milliseconds right now). How do I have to adapt the class to always get the newest image whenever I call capture image?
